# Consolidating await statements

Tags: c#, async-await

I would like to consolidate the following statements into one line.

```
var x = await A.Method1Async();
var y = await x.Method2Async();
var z = await y.Method3Async();
```

Is it possible to remove the intermediate objects and have this in one line ?

Comment: so you mean something like `await A.Method1Async().Method2Async().Method3Async();`?

Comment: @DLeh: That will not compile.

Comment: i know, i'm just trying to understand what he's looking for

Comment: @Dleh , yes something like that. Not sure if I can use .ContinueWith() ?

Comment: @user82383: You can, but you don't need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
var z = await (await (await A.Method1Async()).Method2Async()).Method3Async();
```

Comment: Though exactly what was asked for, I'd be inclined to stick with the original code as it's much more readable!

Comment: Thanks everyone, the original syntax is much more readable. I will probably stick to that